# Headless Windows - Render GUI?

Tags: c#, windows, user-interface, automation, ui-automation

I am working with headless virtual desktop images and I have a need to monitor a desktop and watch the UI (without using RDP or VNC) actions.  UI actions are possible only because of a workaround to actively create new RDP sessions every X minutes.  This is managed by a policy and I have no control over the RDP session creation.

I have worked on a C# application that takes screenshots of the Windows Desktop and streams those screenshots out via a port (application listens on a port). To generate screenshots, I am using the standard `Graphics.CopyFromScreen Method` which works fine if someone is connected via RDP or the desktop monitor is active.

If the desktop is not active via RDP (or is between the session creations every x minutes) I eventually end up getting error `The handle is invalid` which I assume is because Windows is no longer rendering the UI. At this point nothing is rendered, but if I or the policy logs in to RDP then everything starts rendering again (albeit temporarily until the next time the policy again takes effect).

Is there a way to tell Windows to keep the GUI rendered?  What options do I have here?